# VBS - Find SCCM Collection Id's, Names and Package Names a computer is apart of?

Tags: vbscript, sccm

Currently I have 'excel SQL query' for subject requirement and it is executing fine without any issues.

**Current Excel SQL query Script:** I have created SQL query which is connect to SCCM server and get the below details.

*Excel 2013/2016-> Data -> Connections-> Workbook Connections->*
[Excel SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5cCZ.jpg)

**Connection String:**

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=CM_CAS;Data Source=<SCCMServerIP>;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=<SCCMServerHostName>;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False
```

**Command Type:** SQL

**Command Text:**

```
DECLARE @machname varchar(max)

SET @machname = '<DeviceHostName>'

select CollectionID,CollectionName,packagename,@machname as MachineName from v_AdvertisementInfo 

-- select AssignmentID,AssignmentName,CollectionID,CollectionName,ApplicationName,AppModelID from v_ApplicationAssignment

where CollectionID in 

(select FCM.CollectionId from dbo.v_R_System r join 

dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership FCM on R.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID join 

dbo.v_Collection C on C.CollectionID = FCM.CollectionID Where R.Name0 

= @machname) and 

ProgramName not like '%Remove%'and 
 ProgramName not like '%Un-Install%'and 
 CollectionName not like '%Test%' and
CollectionName not like '%temp%'


union

select CollectionID,CollectionName,ApplicationName,@machname as MachineName from v_ApplicationAssignment
where CollectionID in 

(select FCM.CollectionId from dbo.v_R_System r join 

dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership FCM on R.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID join 

dbo.v_Collection C on C.CollectionID = FCM.CollectionID Where R.Name0 

= @machname) and

CollectionName not like '%Test%' and
CollectionName not like '%temp%'
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

And example Excel output will be as below for

```
hostname 'IN-00001236'
```

[Result/Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5dpW.jpg)

**Requirement is :** for Laptop EOL refresh

Gather all collection id's which is member of `IN-00001236` (EOL Device) and add new device host name `(IN-1111)` into result collection id's! then delete `IN-00001236` from SCCM. Generate report in excel/CSV?

I have a challenge In above Excel SQL Query? like I have add/replace hostname every `time/run` under `'Command Text'`

So, I need to automate this complete process using VBS or PS?

Comment: There are very powerful PS Cmdlets available for SCCM, that are part of the sccm console, but can not easily be installed on a standalone computer. Would you run this from a computer where the sccm console is installed or not? (there are working solutions for both scenarios I'd say just checking which one would be the best fit)

Comment: Yes, this was ran in standalone computer (win 7 & later). Currently we are using this script in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I completed VBS as below. it's working fine.

```
Dim connect, sql, resultSet, pth, txt

Set ObjFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set connect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connect.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=CM_CAS;Data Source=<SCCMServerIP>;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=<SCCMServerHostName>;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Trusted_Connection=True;"
connect.Open

sql="select CollectionID,CollectionName,packagename,<HostName> as MachineName from v_AdvertisementInfo where CollectionID in (select FCM.CollectionId from dbo.v_R_System r join dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership FCM on R.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID join dbo.v_Collection C on C.CollectionID = FCM.CollectionID Where R.Name0 = 'HostName') and ProgramName not like '%Remove%'and ProgramName not like '%Un-Install%'and CollectionName not like '%Test%' and CollectionName not like '%temp%' union select CollectionID,CollectionName,ApplicationName,@machname as MachineName from v_ApplicationAssignment where CollectionID in (select FCM.CollectionId from dbo.v_R_System r join dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership FCM on R.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID join dbo.v_Collection C on C.CollectionID = FCM.CollectionID Where R.Name0 = 'HostName') and CollectionName not like '%Test%' and CollectionName not like '%temp%'"

Set resultSet = connect.Execute(sql)

pth = "C:\test\test.csv"

Set txt = ObjFSO.CreateTextFile(pth, True)

On Error Resume Next
resultSet.MoveFirst
Do While Not resultSet.eof
  txt.WriteLine(resultSet(0) & "," & resultSet(1) & "," & resultSet(2))
  resultSet.MoveNext
Loop

resultSet.Close
connect.Close
Set connect = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want a new record to have all memberships of the old record.

In my opinion you can focus only on collection memberships, whether the deployment to a collection is a package, application or update should not be important as long as the collections are the same.

So first you would need to translate your devices name to a resourceid as those are the primary key in all sccm tables:

```
$WS = 'IN-00001236'
$resourceID = (Get-WmiObject -Class "SMS_R_System" -Filter "(Name = '$WS')" | Select-Object -last 1).ResourceID
```

once you have that you can get all the collection members

```
$collectionMembers = (Get-WmiObject -Class "SMS_FullCollectionMembership" -Filter "(ResourceID = '$resourceID')"  | where { $_.IsDirect -eq $true }).CollectionID
```

to delete a record use this

```
[void](Get-WmiObject -Class "SMS_R_System" -Filter "(ResourceID = '$resourceID')").Delete()
```

now you have to add those to the new record (first get resourceID again)

```
Foreach($CollID in $collectionMembers) {
    $CollectionQuery = Get-WmiObject -Class "SMS_Collection" -Filter "CollectionID = '$CollID'"
    $directRule = (Get-WmiObject -List -Class "SMS_CollectionRuleDirect").CreateInstance()
    $directRule.ResourceClassName = "SMS_R_System"
    $directRule.ResourceID = $newResourceID
    [void]$CollectionQuery.AddMemberShipRule($directRule)
}
```

If you want to use this for multiple devices in a loop you can just create a csv file with `oldrecord,newrecord`
import with

```
$records = Import-Csv <path to csv> -Header old,new
```

and then use a loop outside all the code like

```
foreach ($record in $records) {
  # inside here use $record.old or $record.new for the old/new names like
  # $WS = $record.old
}
```

Now i don't know if you even would need the excel file anymore if you just have a script doing the work, but in case you really do you can create a excel readable csv from powershell with export-csv (might need options like -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 to be easily readable)

In theory you can execute your whole sql query in powershell as well

```
$sqlText = "your query"
$SQLConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection("Server=<sccmserver>;Database=<sccm db>;Integrated Security=SSPI")
$SQLConnection.Open();

$cmd = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sqlText, $SQLConnection);    
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

while ($reader.Read()) {
    $reader["<columnname>"] 
}
```

and recreate your file in the ps script